# How to prevent repeated processing of failed message by ask pattern in Akka?

Tags: scala, akka, fault-tolerance

*Original description is updated after some investigation*:

When I send a message to an actor via the Ask pattern, and the actor fails with an exception, the message is processed again.

The exact number of retries varies, and I was not able to understand the principle. In most of my experiments, a failing message is retried 3 times.

How can I fine-tune the Ask-pattern behavior (e.g. set a predictable number of retries)?

Comment: How about adding a number of attempts to the message itself? When the message comes in, create a clone with incremented counter. Then you can check whether the number of attempts exceeds the limit and drop the message within an actor itself? `case RetryMessage(payload, counter) if counter > limit => // drop it`

Answer (score 1):

You questions is somewhat confusing to me as I think what you describe as the default is not the default. A failed message is not processed 3 times by default. By default, if an exception occurs in an Actor, it is restarted and continues with the next message. See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/fault-tolerance.html#Default_Supervisor_Strategy

So to your questions:

> How can I implement the logic which will restart my actor, but will
>   skip failed message and will not try to process it again and again?

That's the default.

> How is the default supervisor on guardian actor implemented? If
>   someone has an idea how to find this place in their Github, it would
>   be quite helpful.

https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/FaultHandling.scala#L154

Comment: I did some investigation and it turned out that using ask-pattern caused all those retries. I updated the description